# Web Scraping Values on a table on a website . Python, BeautifulSoup, Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am new to Python and am trying to make web scraping programs to complement those I mentioned in my other question which was recently solved (thank you!). I want the program to scrape a value in a table. At the bottom, I have a snip attached with the value I am trying to scrape circled.

[image: Value I want to scrape]

Link to the site being scraped:

https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/$SPX/technical-analysis

Here is the portion of the code I have for the web scraping portion currently. I am using beautiful soup and requests. It currently returns "None" in the IDLE. All help on this is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

```
import bs4

import requests

res = requests.get('https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/$SPX/technical-analysis')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

DMA = soup.find(class_='up')

print(DMA)
```

Answer (score 0):

With bs4 4.7.1+ you can use :contains to target the previous sibling node by text value then use adjacent sibling combinator with class selector to move to the value you want. Remember to add user-agent header.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

res = requests.get('https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/$SPX/technical-analysis', headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
dma = soup.select_one('td:contains("200-Day") + .up').text.strip()
print(dma)
```